# how to write function about return data

Tags: system-verilog

all,i need help.i encounter question about array data transaction.Please help me!
   code is following.
   packet is data class,and there is three queue,R,G,B,and in module "test",arith function 's return_data is no data. why?
    question:though "into-arith" function,output tr_out is no data.

```
class packet # (int bit_depth =16);//packet class

  bit [bit_depth-1:0] R[$];
  bit [bit_depth-1:0] G[$];
  bit [bit_depth-1:0] B[$];

endclass
```

//packet is data class

```
module test #(active_num=1920);   //

    packet in_tr [4];

    initial begin
        foreach(in_tr[i]) begin
            in_tr[i] = new();
        end
        foreach(in_tr[j]) begin
            for(int i=0;i<1920;i++) begin
                in_tr[j].R.push_back(i);
            end
        end
        process_in_tr;
    end

    task process_in_tr();
       packet tr_out[4];

       foreach(tr_out[i])begin
            tr_out[i] = new();
       end

       tr_out[4] = into_arith(in_tr);

       foreach(tr_out[j]) begin
           foreach(tr_out[j].R[i]) begin
               $display("%h",tr_out[j].R[i]);
           end
       end
    endtask


    function packet[4] into_arith(ref packet in_tr[4]);
       packet tr_tmp[4];

       foreach(tr_tmp[i]) begin
            tr_tmp[i] = new();
       end

       for(int m=0;m<4;m++) begin
           foreach(in_tr[m].R[i]) begin
               tr_tmp[m].R.push_back(in_tr[m].R[i]);
               tr_tmp[m].G.push_back(in_tr[m].G[i]);
               tr_tmp[m].B.push_back(in_tr[m].B[i]);
           end
       end

      return tr_tmp[4];
    endfunction

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't event get this to compile in Questa, there are many syntax errors.

The three main problems are

1. The declaration of the function is an error. You must use a typedef when returning an aggregate type (in your case an unpacked array of packet#())
2. the assignment `tr_out[4] = into_arith(in_tr);` is illegal. You are trying to assign a unpacked array of 4 elements to the 5th element of an array, which doesn't even exist.
3. The `return tr_tmp[4];` is also illegal. You are trying to return the non-existent 5th element of an array as the return value for a function that requires a 4-element array.

See all my corrections below:

```
class packet # (int bit_depth =16);//packet class
  bit [bit_depth-1:0] R[$];
  bit [bit_depth-1:0] G[$];
  bit [bit_depth-1:0] B[$];
endclass 

//packet is data class

module test #(active_num=1920);   //

   typedef packet#() packet4_t[4];

    packet4_t in_tr;

    initial begin
       foreach(in_tr[j]) begin
          in_tr[j] = new();
          for(int i=0;i<1920;i++)
            in_tr[j].R.push_back(i);
       end
       process_in_tr;
    end

    task process_in_tr();
       packet4_t tr_out;

       tr_out = into_arith(in_tr);

       foreach(tr_out[j]) begin
           foreach(tr_out[j].R[i]) begin
               $display("%h",tr_out[j].R[i]);
           end
       end
    endtask

    function automatic packet4_t into_arith(ref packet4_t in_tr);
       packet4_t tr_tmp;

       foreach(tr_tmp[i]) begin
          tr_tmp[i] = new();

          tr_tmp[m].R = in_tr[m].R;
          tr_tmp[m].G = in_tr[m].G;
          tr_tmp[m].B = in_tr[m].B;   
          /* assigments above are the same as the foreach loop below
      foreach(in_tr[m].R[i]) begin
             tr_tmp[m].R.push_back(in_tr[m].R[i]);
             tr_tmp[m].G.push_back(in_tr[m].G[i]);
             tr_tmp[m].B.push_back(in_tr[m].B[i]);
           end */
       end

       return tr_tmp;
    endfunction

endmodule
```